# How to select product with multiple categories

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

According my title of question so i have structure for Access database like this:

**Category**

```
categoryid   categoryname
1            one
2            two
3            three
```

**Product table:**

```
productid    productname    categories
1            one            1,2,3
2            two            3
3            three          1,2
```

**When i have categoryid is 1** I dont know the way to  select product have multiple categorise. Because when i use **In** operator,i am getting some error..

```
Select * from product where categories In (categodyid) because cannot compare a collection with one value.
```

i'm stuck at here! Please help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your tables are not normalized.  Look at the Categories column in Product Table.  Each cell should have only one value.  By allowing multiple values, you risk various problems including update/insert anomalies and what you are seeing now.  You also make it very difficult to do selects and other operations.  Instead, think about normalizing your tables with this example:

**Category**

```
categoryid   categoryname
1            one
2            two
3            three
```

**Product**

```
ProdductId   ProductName
4            prod1
5            prod2
6            prod 3
```

**Category_Prod**

```
CategoryId   ProductId
1            3
1            4
2            3
```

The third table acts as a way to remedy the many to many pattern.  If you have any questions on how to do this or how to use it, let me know

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic parent-child one-to-many relationship. You need a `[ProductCategory]` table to associate a given Product with multiple Categories:

```
productid  categoryid
1          1
1          2
1          3
2          3
3          1
3          2
```